# Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON is not working on Moto X

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera-flash

I m testing my app on moto x and even after setting flash mode on, flash is not working. App is working fine in other devices but not on Moto X.
here is a code snippet

```
    cameraInstance = getCameraInstance(cameraId);

    // Setting the right parameters in the camera
    Camera.Parameters params = cameraInstance.getParameters();
    List<Size> list = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    Size s = list.get(0);
    for (Size size : list)
    {
        if (s.height < size.height)
            s = size;
    }

    params.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);
    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(85);
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);

    cameraInstance.setParameters(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems as in moto x, flash operation works only with some combination of Camera preview size and Camera picture size. I used different combination and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me with 1280x720 for the preview size.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see : [Camera FLASH_MODE_ON not working on Moto X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466602/camera-flash-mode-on-not-working-on-moto-x) ?

What is

```
Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
Log.i("camera", param.flatten().toString());
```

logging ? =)

Comment: I saw that post but it didn't help. I can enable torch mode by setting parmas.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) and it works. But setting flash mode to Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON and Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using the flash with any alternative Camera App from Google Play on your device ? Maybe that Motorola completely screwed up the Camera API on the Moto X (as your code looks correct and is working on other devices) :/

Comment: Yes, alternative apps work. This is a problem with the camera API it appears. I am still stuck on this, and would love to hear if anyone else has been able to solve.

Comment: @RealCasually see my answer below. I am not sure though whether it is the only possible way and is it the only reason why flash is misbehaving. But it worked.